# Python RandomInfo Library TypeError: get_email() got unexpected argument

Tags: python

I just started writing some code in python using the randominfo library

https://pypi.org/project/randominfo/

In my code I have:

```
from randominfo import get_email, Person

get_email(Person = None)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: get_email() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Person'
```

I am calling it exactly the way it is in the documentation but I get this error. I am using pycharm IDE with python 3.8.  I cannot figure out why this happens.

Comment: If you want the generated address to be completely random, just call `get_email()` with no parameter.  (The parameter is actually named `prsn`, I don't know why the documentation has that wrong.)

Comment: I tried both, still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I found instantiating the Person object first to work for me.

```
import randominfo as ri

class Person:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.first_name = ri.get_first_name()
        self.last_name = ri.get_last_name()
        self.birthdate = ri.get_birthdate()

person1 = Person()
print(ri.get_email(person1))
```